# Atmosphere websocket returning multiple objects

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

I'm using the Atmosphere Framework for websockets and I didn't understand the response I got from Atmosphere, perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

Essentially, I have several types of messages the user sends to the server websocket, each defined as a MessageBean with parameter "type" to distinguish between each type of message using the Google Gson RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory class.

This all works fine, but the problem is when I encode the message back to the user:

```
@Message(decoders = {MessageServer.class}, encoders = {MessageServer.class})
public MessageProtocolBean onMessage(AtmosphereResource atmosphereResource,      
    MessageBean message) throws IOException {
    if (message instanceof ChatBean) {
       ... do stuff
       return new MessgeProtocolBean(chatBean);
    } else {
    ...
    }

})
```

Now MessageProtocolBean can be something like the following:

```
public class MessageProtocolBean {

    private String message;
    private ChatBean chat = new ChatBean(); 
    private List<ChatBean> chats = new ArrayList<ChatBean>();
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    private List<AlertBean> alerts = new ArrayList<AlertBean>();
    private Map<String,ContactBean> contacts = new 
           HashMap<String,ContactBean>();

    public MessageProtocolBean(ChatBean chat) {
            this.chat = chat;
    }

    public MessageProtocolBean(ChatBean chat, Collection<User> users, 
       Map<String,ContactBean> contacts, Collection<AlertBean> alerts) {
            this.chat = chat;
            this.users.addAll(users);
            this.contacts.putAll(contacts);
            this.alerts.addAll(alerts);
    }
```

Now when the user sends just a chat message, the returned object to all clients is the JavaScript object:

```
Object { chat: {…}, chats: [], users: [], alerts: [], contacts: {} }
```

Note the "chat" parameter is not empty, but all others are, despite the fact only a chat message was returned. What I am unsure about is although I have specified return MessageProtocolBean(ChatBean chat), why do I get all?